# opengl rotation and translation in order to drawing the stonehenge

Tags: c, opengl

I am new to openGL, my problem is that when I execute a rotation into Y axis, the function glRotatef makes a bad traslation. I can not understand how rotation function works, so could someone explain me this plis?

My code:

**Places every arc in place:**

```
void CreaStone(void)
{
    stone = glGenLists(1);
    if (stone != 0)
    {   int i = 0;
    int rotation = 15;
    float translationX = 2;
    float translationZ = 0;
    float fact = 0.2;
    glNewList(stone, GL_COMPILE);
    for(i = 0; i<5; ++i){
        /*Crear cada stone*/
        glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(0.15,0.15,0.15);
        glRotatef(rotation, 0,1,0);
        glTranslatef(translationX,0,0);
        arco();
        glPopMatrix();
        translationX = translationX + 2;
        //translationZ = translationZ + 1.8;
        fact += 0.2;
        rotation = rotation + 15;
    }

    glEndList();

    }

}
```

**Displays the stonehenge elemental component**

```
void arco(void)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(0.25,0.6,0.25);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(45, 0, 2, 0);
    igWireCubo(4, 4);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(45, 0, 2, 0);
    glTranslatef(4,0,4);
    igWireCubo(4, 4);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(1.250,0.20,0.25);
    glTranslatef(0,2,0);
    glTranslatef(0.566,0,0);
    glRotatef(45, 0, 2, 0);
    //glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
    igWireCubo(4, 4);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

**Draws a cube**

```
void igWireCubo(int pu, int pv)
{
    igCreateQuadricObject(pu, pv, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f);
}
```

**Generates a primitive object**

```
void igCreateQuadricObject (int pu, int pv, float uMax, float vMax, float R, float s1, float s2)
{
    float u, v, inc_u, inc_v;
    float x, y, z;
    int   i,j;
    v= 0.0f;
    u = 0.0f;
    inc_u = uMax / pu;
    inc_v = vMax/ pv;

    for (i = 0; i <= pu; ++i) {

        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        for (j = 0; j<= pu; ++j)
        {
            x = xSuperQuadric(u, v, R, s1, s2);
            y = ySuperQuadric(u, v, R, s1, s2);
            z = zSuperQuadric(u, v, R, s1, s2);
            glVertex3f(x, y, z);
            u = u + inc_u;}
        u = 0.0f;
        glEnd();
        v = v + inc_v;

    }

    v = 0.0f;
    u = 0.0f;

    for (i = 0; i <= pu; ++i) {

        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for (j = 0; j <= pv; ++j)
        {
            x = xSuperQuadric(u, v, R, s1, s2);
            y = ySuperQuadric(u, v, R, s1, s2);
            z = zSuperQuadric(u, v, R, s1, s2);
            glVertex3f(x, y, z);
            v = v + inc_v;

        }
        v = 0.0f;
        glEnd();
        u = u + inc_u;

    }

}
```

[image: My result from a top view]

Comment: It is not `glRotate`. You call `glTranslatef(translationX,0,0);` and increment `translationX` for each object you draw, so why are you surprised that this happens?

Comment: @ybungalobill Yes, he used wrong expressions but still according to the picture he has problem mostly with rotation. The 'stones' seems to be (almost) at the right position but not the right rotation.

Comment: glRotate(angle, x,y,z) rotates x,y,z coordinates by angle, pretty simple. to rotate 45 on x glRotate(45,1,0,0); Your result is almost a 'stonehenge' I think all you have to do is think through the math once more.

Comment: @eldo: I doubt that. They look all rotated by constant amount, at the time they are spiraling out rather than being located on a circle.

Comment: @ybungalobill I dont say the translation is fine, I say "glRotatef makes a bad traslation" he is trying to say they not in the right rotation, as they all should face the middle.

Comment: thanks, I am working on it